# problem with selector in react.js . If i use selector in react.js and if i export in one of the component it shows error in that selector part

Tags: reactjs, undefined, selector, use-state, optional-chaining

```
export const initialState = {
  basket: [],
};

// reducer takes care about adding and removing items from the basket

// selector
export const getBasketTotal = (basket) =>
  basket?.reduce((amount, item) => item.price + amount, 0);

// the above code helps us tally the total amount of products

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD TO BASKET":
      return {
        ...state,
        basket: [...state.basket, action.items],
      };
    // the above code helps us to push items to the basket with current elemnts in the basket
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default reducer;
```

[image]

the error it is shows is  in export const getBasketTotal and the error it shows is anonymous function

Answer (score 0):

Selectors typically receive the *entire* state object. I suspect you want to access a `state.basket`.

```
export const getBasketTotal = (state) =>
  state.basket?.reduce((amount, item) => item.price + amount, 0);
```

Something else that looks a little suspect to me is the `"ADD TO BASKET"` action:

```
basket: [...state.basket, action.items],
```

`action.items` IMO implies multiple items, so I think you may want to spread the items into the `basket` array.

```
basket: [...state.basket, ...action.items],
```